# Passing variables to system function in C

Tags: c, linux, function, input, system

I have this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a;

    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Your number is: %d\n",a);
    system("echo %d",a);
}
```

I'm interested in the last command, the `system()` function and why I can't print my variable like i printed it with `printf()`. I want to be able to ask the user some input , let's say a string and then pass it to the system function.

**Practical example:**

Ask user for folder name

```
system("mkdir %s", FolderName);
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: just read the doc man system: `int system(const char *command);` You have to build your command into a buffer

Answer (score 12):

Use `snprintf`

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                             
#include <stdlib.h>                                                            

int main()                                                                     
{                                                                              
    int a;                                                                     
    char buf[BUFSIZ];                                                          

    printf("Please enter a number:\n");                                        
    scanf("%d",&a);                                                            
    printf("Your number is: %d\n",a);                                          
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "echo %d",a);                                   
    system(buf);                                                               
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`system`, unlike `printf` does not accept multiple parameters, it only accepts one parameter, a `const char *command`. So you need to build your complete command string first in memory and then pass it to system.

An example would be:

```
char buf[32];
sprintf(buf, "echo %d", a);
system(buf);
```

You need to take care not to write more chars into buf than buf has space for. You might want to read the man page for `snprintf` to rewrite the code in a safer way.

Also: if your code really compiled, then please compile with a higher warning level. At least that would have given you warnings that you are calling system with more parameters than you should.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in sprint, it's sprintf

Comment: @BorjaDíazdeTerán Thanks, I edited my answer. Next time, you can just edit the answer yourself, that is how SO works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to edit your answer because it was just one character (strange restriction...).

Answer (score 1):

The System function doesnt have the formatting options like printf, instead the system function takes a C string as a parameter.

Check out the following site for more info.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_system.htm

Comment: Thank you fellas for helping me in such short manner. I have tried Ôrel's code and it works. I really do not like the fact that I don't know what's going on so now I have something to work on. Don't fear - I'm no copy + paste type of dude. I like to learn what happens. Thanks for the helpful links. I have some reading to do now :)