# Pass a value from a C variable to an embedded shell script?

Tags: c, bash, arguments

Is this possible?

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char testString[]="blunt"

#define shellscript1 "\
#/bin/bash \n\
printf \"\nHi! The passed value is: $1\n\" \n\
"

int main(){

    system(shellscript1);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I would like to pass a value from `testString` to `shellscript1` without having to reserve to making a temporary external script.

I've been ***bashing*** my head, and I couldn't figure out how to do it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to pass testString as argument to shellscript1?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes. Is there a way?

Comment: you could use `putenv` and call the script with that variable instead of $1

Comment: you could just `popen("bash")` and feed it your bash commands.

Comment: This might help: [C: Anyway to load parameters into a system() call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5482832/3776858) or [Passing variables to system function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30305619/3776858)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and Cyrus, I shall read into all of them. Thanks!

Comment: don't bash your head anymore when you can feed it to a python :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the environment is possibly the simplest way to achieve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char testString[]="blunt";
#define shellscript1 "bash -c 'printf \"\nHi! The passed value is: $testString\n\"'"
int main()
{
    if(0>setenv("testString",testString,1)) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0!=system(shellscript1)) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    return 0;
}
```

There are other ways, like generating the `system` argument in a buffer (e.g., with `sprintf`) or not using `system`.

`system` treats its argument like a a string to come after `"/bin/sh", "-c"`. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52914892/1084774) to [using system() with command line arguments in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914641/using-system-with-command-line-arguments-in-c/52914892#52914892)  I coded up a simple `my_system` alternative that takes the arguments as a string array.

With it, you can do:

```
#define shellscript1 "printf \"\nHi! The passed value is: $1\n\" \n"
char testString[]="blunt";
int main()
{
    if(0!=my_system("bash", (char*[]){"bash", "-c", shellscript1, "--", testString,0})) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for coding our comments into reality :) I'm running windows so I couldn't risk to post a non-working solution.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Added a slightly more original solution so I'm not just copying the comments. :)

Comment: of course there was no snark in my answer as you probably understood, but I prefered to re-state it. Good answer

Comment: @PSkocik beautiful and elegant solution. Thank you, kind sir.